# Self-tracking entities template missing

Tags: .net, entity-framework

When i create an entity data model and select Add Code Generation Item i don't see any ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator(i only see ADO.NET EntityObject Generator). What may be the problem?
I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate. I installed and then uninstalled ado.net entity framework ctp 3.

Answer (score 0):

This generator is normally included with Visual Studio 2010 (whereas the POCO one is found in the online gallery). Try running `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` to reinstall the templates.